# Using MONTH(NOW()) in one command with MAX()

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, time

In mysql, how to using function SELECT MONTH (now()) in another query statement ? \n

I asked this coz I have to created a form that have a unique format.

The format is XXX/IT/month/no_request.

XXX : is my company, IT is my departemnt, month is january to december, 
and no_request is an auto_increment number

So, this is my story board.
I have created a table that named tbl_request like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_request` (
 `id_request` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `id_user` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `name_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id_request`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_request_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using codeigniter to develop this app,
Now, I am created the model that representation of tbl_request . And now, this is the function to get the id.

```
    public function getID(){
    $this->load->helper('date');

    $datestring = "%m";
    $time = time();
    $month = mdate($datestring, $time);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT max(id_request) as max_id FROM tbl_request WHERE id_request LIKE '%TMS/IT/MONTH(NOW())/%' ");
    $id = $query->row();


        $no = (int) substr($id->max_id, 10,3);
        $no++;
        $idrequest = "TMS/IT/$month/".sprintf("%03s", $no);
        return $idrequest;

}

 public function insertRequest($id_request, $id_user, $name_user){
     $query = INSERT INTO `tbl_request` VALUES ('$id_request', 
                                               '$id_user', 
                                               '$nama_user');
     return $query;
}
```

So, in controller, I just write this :

```
$id_request = $this->model_request->getID();
$insert_data = $this->model_request->insertRequest($id_request, id_user, username);
```

The big problem is : This code gives me an error like this :

```
Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 'TMS/IT/12/001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I think, my code is not working in this line :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT max(id_request) as max_id FROM tbl_request WHERE id_request LIKE '%TMS/IT/MONTH(NOW())/%' ");
```

N.P : Now, I just can inserting a row that is XXX/IT/12/001, in next like 002 is failed.
How can I make this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your $id->max is returning NULL and with ++ operator it becomes 1, which already exists in your database, so to resolve this problem you need to fix your select max query like this :

```
SELECT max(id_request) as max_id 
FROM tbl_request 
WHERE id_request LIKE CONCAT('TMS/IT/',MONTH(NOW()),'/%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is little wrong.
If you want use max, where , and no++ yo must use a integer for id.

You must use integer id, and merge strings.

Example
id field : 1,2,,,,,,,

select max(id)+1 from table

after finish query , you must merge tms/id/month and ... ...

I added basic design picture [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is bad idea to generate unique ID outside DB. In your case you can easy get two or more requests trying to insert the same ID's. I advice you use primary key as usual autoinc in DB. And the task of getting your TMS/IT/.. will be decided by merging ID column with other column or constant values.

Comment: Its a bad idea to generate SURROGATE keys outside the DBMS. But its far from clear from the question as to whether a natural key might exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not work as written.

```
SELECT max(id_request) as max_id 
FROM tbl_request 
WHERE id_request LIKE '%TMS/IT/MONTH(NOW())/%'
```

The pattern for the `LIKE` clause, `'%TMS/IT/MONTH(NOW())/%'`, is a character literal.  It will not be evaluated.  Even if you concatenate, `MONTH(NOW())` is a plain integer, not a padded character.  You'll need to use `LPAD()` as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT max(id_request) as max_id 
FROM tbl_request 
WHERE id_request LIKE CONCAT('%TMS/IT/',LPAD(MONTH(NOW()),3,'0'),'/%')
```

However, I don't know if that will work.  You may need to use a parameterized query from PHP that correctly populates the month in your string.

Also, this is precisely why violating first normal form is a really bad idea.  Make four fields and define a composite primary key.